# How do I stop my screen from constantly locking up?

Tags: login, screen, lock-screen

It is not a power-saving or screensaver issue, it is literally every 25 seconds that my screen either blacks out or blacks out and locks so i have to put my password in over and over.  Please help! (It has locked five times in the typing of this paragraph.)

Comment: Could you please state which version and variant of Ubuntu you are using and what kind of setup you've got?

Answer (score 2):

**Go to System > Preferences > Screensaver**

You need to uncheck "Lock screen when screensaver is active"

[image]

If this doesn't work , maybe there is an issue with the graphics drivers or something.
Also please edit your question mention what version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the screen locks, try to open gconf-editor choose desktop, gnome, lockdown and tick the box disable lock screen. If not installed use synaptics to install.